Get-AzRoleAssignment ISSUE
Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/abc/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/adls2sxcuzeow"
output is giving blank display name
Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/abc/resourceGroups/test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/adls2sxcuzeow"
output is giving blank display name"
RoleAssignmentName : fd
RoleAssignmentId   : /providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/xdbx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/fd
Scope              : /providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/dcdd235cac24cd5c
DisplayName        : 
SignInName         : 


If the user or group or service principal or managed identity been deleted after the role assignment. It will show null when get role assignment.
I can re-produce scenario like you:

When I check in Azure portal:


But there are multiple groups users or service principal who has access is there but for all it shows blank value
